# Windows Metro Apps on touch Screen Monitors

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen

I know this might seem odd, but I am working on a windows Metro app which would be displayed on touch screen monitors in our local university. 
Now I am using the simulator for debugging, but in the simulator you have to start "Touch Mode" to even use the touch interface. 
So when using the touch monitors, do we have to specifically specify touch mode ? Or it will automatically integrate the touch functionality ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch is a first class-citizen in Windows Store applications, so no special accommodations are needed.  I would recommend you test on a touch device though before deploying, it's a different way of interacting, and even though the simulator does a decent job of handling the mechanics, it will "feel" different to a user - especially if you're leveraging pinch-zoom, swipe and other gestures.

On another note... is this app intended for a kiosk-type application?  If so, keep in mind with Windows 8/RT, you won't be able to easily prevent the users from swiping to the charms, navigating to other programs, etc.  You may want/need to take a look at [Windows 8 Embedded](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products-solutions-overview.aspx) depending on the specific deployment requirements.

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply, yes this is a kiosk-type application, I will look into the embedded systems for windows 8.